# Node JS mysql native drivers - load balancing splitting read/write queries

Tags: mysql, node.js, load-balancing, read-write

We have an existing high traffic PHP web app which uses the MySQL Native driver's load balancing facility to split read & write queries between a master and slave database.

I'm migrating the API part of this app to NodeJS, currently I'm using the MySQL drivers.

My question: is there a way to split read write queries between master and slave databases in NodeJS? I've looked for a NodeJS version of the MySQL Native drivers but have had no luck as yet.

Thanks in advance for any help provided :)